# Triple Join unique results in each?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm in the process of writing 3 versions of a query, with slightly different conditions for each version. However I'd like to join them like in the join diagram supplied. I don't want any duplicates on any reports, so I specifically want A to have all unique results for A and that contain crossovers for A, B & C. I'd then like B to contain all unique results for B and crossovers for B & C. And finally C to have all unique results for C only.

[image]

The query itself runs fine and is structured as below:

[image]

Thought I''d menton it in case I've got the structure all wrong or potentially could have written it a better way?

Any help to crack this one would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want this for and the answer given is correct, but you might be easier just doing the query once and including three case statements in the select statement to identify how many of the three categories each record falls into.  It'd save you displaying the same records three times.

Comment: I do not understand. a,b and c are sets. what means select a.*,b.*,c.* . Do you really want a full outer join between them and on which field. or you want something like   (a U b U c), which you can get with select * from a union select * from b union select * from c

Comment: Thank you all to answer your questions, because of the ORs in the WHERE conditions I'm getting crossovers, e.g. condition 3 will appear on all 3 queries. What I'm trying to achieve is having 3 sets so that I have a priority system, A then B then C but removing duplicates in the interest of not duplicating work. So say for instance I get 300 results from the query without the additional OR conditions I want to see say 100 in A, 100 in B and 100 in C. Currently I'm getting say 500 results when I know 200 are duplicates due to the crossover conditions. Trying to apply answer below no joy as yet.

Comment: Should also mention ultimately what I will do is once I know the results are not duplicating schedule the 3 versions SELECT DISTINCT a.* then a separate query for SELECT DISTINCT b.* and finally another separate one for SELECT DISTINCT c.* so that they are worked on by 3 different people but I know no duplication of work is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are learning SQL, the first thing you should be aware of is that you are using a join syntax that was outdated more than twenty years ago. It is strange that you learned this such; you must be using a very, very old SQL book. The proper way to join tables t1 and t2 is `from t1 inner join t2 on t2.colx = t1.coly`.

You say you have three groups of conditions on the table, which leads to three queries the result sets thereof you want to combine (which you could do with `UNION ALL`). But some records are in more than one set and you don't want duplicates. Is this all? You could achieve this with `UNION`, which unlike its sibling `UNION ALL` not only glues results together, but also removes duplicates:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from t1
join t2 on t2.colx = t1.coly
where t1.col4 = 4 or t1.col5 = 5
union
select col1, col2, col3
from t1
join t2 on t2.colx = t1.coly
where t1.col4 = 44 or t1.col5 = 55;
```

However, you can achieve this much simpler by combining the conditions:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from t1
join t2 on t2.colx = t1.coly
where t1.col4 = 4 or t1.col5 = 5 or t1.col4 = 44 or t1.col5 = 55;
```

And the last line can be simplified to

```
where t1.col4 in (4, 44) or t1.col5 in (5, 55);
```

by the way. Is that already what you are after or is there something more?

**UPDATE:** From your comments to your request I gather you want to kind of rank your records. What matches the first condition set is group A, then from the remaining records those matching the second condition set is B and the rest is C. Here is how:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
  case when t1.col4 = 4 or t1.col5 = 5 then 'A'
       when t1.col4 = 44 or t1.col5 = 55 then 'B'
       else 'C'
  end as grp
from t1
join t2 on t2.colx = t1.coly
where t1.col4 in (4, 44, 444) and t1.col5 in (5, 55, 555);
```

Or more generally:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
  case when <condition set 1> then 'A'
       when <condition set 2> then 'B'
       else 'C'
  end as grp
from t1
join t2 on t2.colx = t1.coly
where (<condition set 1>) or (<condition set 2>) or (<condition set 3>);
```

**And one more update:** If you want to select C alone, simply apply all conditions as follows:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from t1
join t2 on t2.colx = t1.coly
where (<condition set 3>)
and not (<condition set 1>) 
and not (<condition set 2>);
```

Comment: Thank you for coming back to post the updates, after a bit of trial and error I've got it to do exactly what was needed. And yes totally agree my old school inner joins are just picked up from older scripts the business have in place. Funny thing though the business is 16 years old so I guess they started with outdated syntax! I'm learning as I go so still haven;t invested in a proper book/course but I think it's getting to that time where I should make that step. Thank you again, really much appreciated.